# Making A List Of Links With PHP

Tags: php, arrays, url, hyperlink, echo

I would like to know how to make a list of links appear on my page displaying a name but when you click it, it navigates to the link.

I currently know how to make a list and display the items of it using the foreach command and arrays but is there a way I can make it so I have an array, containing an array, containing the name of the link and the link itself, like so:

```
$links = array(array("Google","//google.co.uk"),array("Bing","//bing.co.uk"))
foreach ($links as $myurl){
foreach ($myurl as $url){
echo "<a href='".$url."'>".$myurl."</a>";
}};
```

I know the above doesn't work but if anyone can help with this problem, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$links = array('Google' => 'www.google.com', 'Yahoo' => 'www.yahoo.com');

foreach($links as $k => $v) {
  echo '<a href="//' . $k . '">' . $v . '</a>'; 
}
```

As you can see I don't specify `http` or `https`, just `//` works on both! See: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml

You can add links to `$links` with:

```
$links['stackoverflow'] = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
```

Comment: You should explain that what he needed was an "associative array" rather than the 2-dimensional array he was trying to use.  He was getting lost in his dimensions.  :)

Comment: Hi Ed, yes.. I added `$links['stackoverflow'] = 'www.stackoverflow.com';` so he can see how `$links` can be populated :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$links = array(
array("Google","//google.co.uk"),
array("Bing","//bing.co.uk")
);

foreach ($links as $urlitem){ 
echo "<a href='".$urlitem[1]."'>".$urlitem[0]."</a>";
}
```

Comment: Creating an extra dimension is unnecessary while `Google` IS the keyvalue of value `www.google.com`

Comment: It is reasonable to adapt the answer to suit the OP's sample data.  This answer, though, is missing its educational explanation and standard code tabbing.